# Magento does not show configurable product options

Tags: magento, product, configurable

I have created some configurable products and simple products associated by using the attribute created 'size'. However, on the product view page, the dropdown menu of the size attribute only has the option of 'Choose an Option...' and my required options are not showing up. All my configurable products and simple products are enabled, visible, have stock >0 and are in stock. Also, I have ticked the simple products at the associated product tab of configurable product. I have searched for the problem but found nothing. I used every single method to fix the problem like re-saving the products but couldn't solve the problem. Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi, can you provide some more information.
What you see when you view a configurable product in Magento Admin would be helpful.
Look down on the bottom you want like associated products and Price Correction Info.

Comment: Hi, I solved my problem. Apparently, my product view page did not load some java script files. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Great, you should Answer your own Question to help other people.
:)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After two days of trying different things, I was able to figure it out. The solution was quite simple. All I had to do was to re-upload the "configurable.phtml" to "app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\type\options".

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Okay. This is a jQuery conflict. I got this same problem and someone provided me a tip on where to find the problem and I solved my own problem.

My posted question:
[magento-does-not-show-configurable-product-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991404/configurable-product-options-not-showing-the-options-on-frontend)

Hope this helps others who are seeking answers.