# Configurable product options not showing the options on Frontend

Tags: magento, product, configurable-product, configurable

I am having problems with the configurable products not showing the options on the frontend. If I use the default theme that came with magento (rwd), all the options are there and working great. But if I select my custom theme, the dropdown options shows nothing but the default "choose an option..."

[image]

I have tried most of the troubleshooting but still the problem persist.

Console errors.
[image]

By the way, my custom theme is based on rwd built-in theme in magento. I only modified most of the styles and copied some phtml from the base folder.

Comment: are there any js errors at console for this page ?

Comment: there are. I'll update my question.

Comment: IF you are using any jquery then you need to mention jQuery.noConflict() code just to mention in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chiragit007 for the hint. I just noticed I got jquery conflicts. I will post my answer to help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem took me a day to figure out what was wrong and now I finally have an answer to my own problem.

Great Tip: Always check for jquery conflicts for this type of issue. thanks to @Chiragit007 for the hint.

[image]

Comment: Great you found it, you can accept your own answer and vote up my comment if you feel like :)

Comment: Thanks to you. :) Can you vote my answer too? so that others will know that this is a best way to check for the problem of this type. Thanks.